# R How to separate simple function like"-17+3" in to numbers eg."-17"and "3"

Tags: regex, r

my data is like
-17+3
2-6
what i need to do is separate each one into two numbers
for example:
-17+3 into "-17" and "3"
2-6 into "2" and "-6"
by using R

many many thanks!

Comment: Do these strings of arithmetic always just involve 2 integers, or can they arbitrarily long?

Comment: `"-17"` could be either a unary `-` applied to the number `17`, or the number `-17`. It would be helpful (both to you and to anyone reading your question) to specify more precisely what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gregexpr`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and [`regmatches`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html) to the rescue:

```
text = '-17+6'
pattern = '[+-]\\d+'
matches = gregexpr(pattern, text)
regmatches(text, matches)
# [[1]]
# [1] "-17" "+6"
```

Comment: Will that regex grab the 2 in `2-6`?  Do you need `-?\\d+` or `[+-]?\\d+`?

Comment: what if I want to add the number?

Comment: like using sum, so that I can get the result of -17+6=-11 ?

Comment: It would probably be best to globally match `-?\d+` then simply add the results together.

Comment: @CAustin how do you add them together? by using sum()?

Comment: However you like, it just wouldn't be part of the regex of course.

Comment: @CAustin but the result is a list, I don't know how to add numbers in a list together.... do you know how to do that? many many thanks!

Comment: @user3525488 Just grab the list’s first entry and send that to `sum`, or use `do.call`. However, you need to make the strings into numbers first anyway: `numbers = as.numeric(regmatches(…)[[1]]); result = sum(numbers)`